# Docky is not showing the correct icon

Tags: nautilus, themes, docky, icons

Hopefully an easy one, I have just installed docky on my media center and it refuses to display the correct icon for nautilus when I have it open. Instead I get an ugly grey box. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a few questions on Launchpad ([1](https://answers.launchpad.net/do/+question/35584), [2](https://answers.launchpad.net/do/+question/75926), and [3](https://answers.launchpad.net/do/+question/116151)), you might actually try looking in `~/.local/share/applications/` instead. I had an issue with a missing icon for Firefox in Do that I was able to fix that way.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your natilus-browser.desktop on `/usr/share/applications` is good.

Open it with `gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus-browser.desktop` and make sure in [Icon] it says «nautilus».

Comment: Did not seem to make any difference.